# In Excel why use INT instead of MOD function to reduce value to a range?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

In the Excel example on page 23 of *Practical Astronomy with your Calculator or Spreadsheet* (by Duffett-Smith and Zwart), cell C13 equals -465.9862462 hours. In order to reduce this value to the range 0 to 24 the authors use the function

```
=C13 - 24*INT(C13/24)
```

to give 14.01375378 hours

Is there a reason why the simpler function

```
=MOD(C13,24)
```

couldn't be used instead? As far as I can see both functions give the same results.

The authors also use a variation of the above INT function to reduce an angle (in degrees) to the range 0 to 360. For example, if cell A1 equals -789 degrees, then the function

```
=A1 - 360*INT(A1/360)
```

gives 291 degrees. As does

```
=MOD(A1,360).
```

So why not use the MOD function?

Thank you.

Comment: Possibly for consistency, although not necessary in this particular instance. The `MOD` function returns an error when dealing with large numbers.  Possibly the author wants to avoid that issue in other astronomical calculations which might have very large numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the official documentation by microsoft, **They are exactly the same thing**

The [official documentation for mod function](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/mod-function-9b6cd169-b6ee-406a-a97b-edf2a9dc24f3) states that:

> The MOD function can be expressed in terms of the INT function:
>
> ```
> MOD(n, d) = n - d*INT(n/d)
> ```

(See the "remarks" section)

So it looks like the author simply doesn't know that MOD() fn exists.